# How to make a great code indentation in HTML from tab identation

Tags: css, html, optimization

i have a Visual Basic code, and i want to put it online on my website, but when i past it in a WYSIWYG editor, my identation disapear... so what is the right method for convert code identation to HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some syntax highlighting library for web display.
There are many out there, just one example:

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to use the `<pre>` tag.  You could also apply `white-space: pre` to your element containing the block of code.  This will preserve your white-space (newlines, tabs, spaces, etc.).

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/